# Ability to create a multi-tab interface, with multiple views open at the same time, using Aurelia

Tags: user-interface, tabs, aurelia

Each tab is a view and each view is loaded and active.  When the user closes the tab by clicking on the [x] the view is then destroy and removed.  Also,  a single view can be loaded multiple times with a different variable, or id.  Think multiple documents of the same type.

Views are created by going to a specific route.

[image: Example Interface]

This can be done by creating your own viewmodel, adding a collection of views,  then adding components as the child views, but this ignores browser history.

After reading it seems the only way to accomplish this is to create your own router.  Although I am not new to Aurelia,  I am not confident enough to create my own router.

The question is how do you maintain browser history and have multiple active views.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is, here.

Comment: 1. You need child router here.
2. Tabs should be placed in template of main VM
3. Tab content should be placed inside <router-view containerless></router-view>

Comment: The question is how to do it.  I will try and think of a better way to ask it.  With some help off of gitter,  I was able to put together a solution that might work.  I will post it when I have a working sample.

Comment: I see the problem here that you can remove the tab, consider you have removed it, and navigate back, you will be switched to the previous route and you should show the removed tab too, it is unusual thing for UI.

Comment: Right, is there a way to remove a browser history item?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of "Patrick Walters @PWKad" on gitter I was able to put together a proof of concept.

I have the example uploaded to github.  Here is the link. https://github.com/BringerOD/AureliaMultiTabExample

The idea is to create routes in your app.js that will handle all of the tabs you will be creating.  All of the routes need to point to one viewmodel that will host, compose, and manage them.

You can add more routes or wildcards as you need them.  Also if your tabs are complex you could create a hash for a parameter.

I have not figured out how to remove an item from the browser history yet.

Hope this helps someone doing the same thing.

```js
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
     
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'shell/:section/:viewmodel/:id'], name: 'shell',      moduleId: 'shell',      nav: false, title: 'shell' }
      
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

The shell page would then display the tabs and compose the views.

```html
<template>
</ul>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li repeat.for="workspace of controller.workSpaces" class="${workspace.isActive ? 'active' : ''}" role="presentation">
                    <a href.bind="workspace.href">
                        <button class="close" type="button">×</button> ${workspace.viewModel} &nbsp;&nbsp; </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="container-fluid" repeat.for="workspace of controller.workSpaces">
                <div show.bind="workspace.isActive" class="container-fluid">
                    
                    <compose containerless view-model="./views/${workspace.section}/${workspace.viewModel}" model.bind="workspace" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```